# Azurerm provider Python CDKTF import issues

Tags: python, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cdk

I am currently trying to figure out why my python cdktf package is not pulling all the correct azurerm provider imports.

Here is my project structure:

```
azure_vd
| > imports
| .gitignore
| cdktf.json
| help
| main-test.py
| main.py
| Pipfile
| Pipfile.lock
```

The steps I have completed:

```
mkdir cdktf-azure-vd
cd cdktf-azure-vd/
cdktf init --template=python

cdktf provider add "azurerm@~>3.63.0"
```

Added to the `cdktf.json` file `"terraformProviders": ["azurerm@~> 3.63.0"],`

I then ran `cdktf get` which generated the `imports` dir.  However, I did not see the following classes here:

```py
...
from imports.azurerm import (
    AzurermProvider,
    VirtualDesktopWorkspace,
    VirtualDesktopHostPool,
    VirtualDesktopApplicationGroup,
    VirtualNetwork,
)
...
```

So I followed up with `pipenv install cdktf-cdktf-provider-azurerm`.

I am not sure what else I am missing, unless the provider class names have changed? Am I setting up this cdktf python project incorrectly? Is there a Pipenv piece I am missing? This is my first time using cdktf, so apologies for any naivety.

The error when I run `cdk synth` is as follows:

```
⠹  Synthesizing
[2023-07-04T18:01:23.074] [ERROR] default - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mason/Documents/CODE/mason_azure_vd/main.py", line 4, in <module>

[2023-07-04T18:01:23.075] [ERROR] default -     from imports.azurerm import (
ERROR: cdktf encountered an error while synthesizing

Synth command: pipenv run python main.py
Error:         non-zero exit code 1

Command output on stderr:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/mason/Documents/CODE/mason_azure_vd/main.py", line 4, in <module>
        from imports.azurerm import (
    ImportError: cannot import name 'AzurermProvider' from 'imports.azurerm' (/home/mason/Documents/CODE/mason_azure_vd/imports/azurerm/__init__.py)
```

This makes sense, because I am not seeing `AzurermProvider`, `VirtualDesktopWorkspace`, `VirtualDesktopHostPool`, `VirtualDesktopApplicationGroup`, `VirtualNetwork` in the `imports` directory.  However, everything I have searched the past two days, including online examples from Terraform on github, point to these class names being correct ?

For posterity here are is some of my code:

`main.py`

```py
from constructs import Construct
from cdktf import App, TerraformStack, CloudBackend, NamedCloudWorkspace
from imports.azurerm import (
    AzurermProvider,
    VirtualDesktopWorkspace,
    VirtualDesktopHostPool,
    VirtualDesktopApplicationGroup,
    VirtualNetwork,
)


class MyStack(TerraformStack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
        super().__init__(scope, id)

        # Initialize the Azure provider
        AzurermProvider(self, "azure", features=[{}])

        # Create a Virtual Network
        virtual_network = VirtualNetwork(
            self,
            "virtual-network",
            name="my-vnet",
            location="westus2",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-resource-group",
            address_space=["10.0.0.0/16"],
            subnets=[{"name": "default", "address_prefix": "10.0.0.0/24"}],
        )

        # Create an Azure Virtual Desktop Workspace
        workspace = VirtualDesktopWorkspace(
            self,
            "workspace",
            name="virtual-desktop-workspace",
            location="westus2",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-resource-group",
        )

        # Create an Azure Virtual Desktop Host Pool
        host_pool = VirtualDesktopHostPool(
            self,
            "host-pool",
            name="virtual-desktop-host-pool",
            location="westus2",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-resource-group",
            workspace_id=workspace.id,
            friendly_name="Virtual Desktop Host Pool",
            type="Pooled",
            vm_template="Windows-11",
            vm_disk_type="Premium",
            vm_disk_size_gb=128,
        )

        # Create an Azure Virtual Desktop Application Group

        application_group = VirtualDesktopApplicationGroup(
            self,
            "application-group",
            name="virtual-desktop-application-group",
            location="westus2",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-application-group-resource-group",
            workspace_id=workspace.id,
            host_pool_id=host_pool.id,
            friendly_name="Virtual Desktop Application Group",
            application_group_type="RemoteApp",
            allow_public_access=True,
        )


app = App()
stack = MyStack(app, "azure_vd")
CloudBackend(
    stack,
    hostname="app.terraform.io",
    organization="redacted-org",
    workspaces=NamedCloudWorkspace("azure_vd_poc"),
)

app.synth()
```

`cdktf.json`

```json
{
  "language": "python",
  "app": "pipenv run python main.py",
  "projectId": "redacted project id",
  "sendCrashReports": "true",
  "terraformProviders": ["azurerm@~> 3.63.0"],
  "terraformModules": [],
  "codeMakerOutput": "imports",
  "context": {

  }
}
```

`pipfile`:

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[requires]
python_version = "3.11"

[dev-packages]
black = "*"

[packages]
cdktf-cdktf-provider-azurerm = "~=9.0.2"
```

output from `pipenv graph`:

```
cdktf-cdktf-provider-azurerm==9.0.2
  - cdktf [required: >=0.17.0,<0.18.0, installed: 0.17.0]
    - constructs [required: >=10.0.25,<11.0.0, installed: 10.2.68]
      - jsii [required: >=1.84.0,<2.0.0, installed: 1.84.0]
        - attrs [required: >=21.2,<24.0, installed: 23.1.0]
        - cattrs [required: >=1.8,<23.2, installed: 23.1.2]
          - attrs [required: >=20, installed: 23.1.0]
        - importlib-resources [required: >=5.2.0, installed: 5.12.0]
        - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
        - python-dateutil [required: Any, installed: 2.8.2]
          - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
        - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
        - typing-extensions [required: >=3.7,<5.0, installed: 4.7.1]
      - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
      - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
    - jsii [required: >=1.79.0,<2.0.0, installed: 1.84.0]
      - attrs [required: >=21.2,<24.0, installed: 23.1.0]
      - cattrs [required: >=1.8,<23.2, installed: 23.1.2]
        - attrs [required: >=20, installed: 23.1.0]
      - importlib-resources [required: >=5.2.0, installed: 5.12.0]
      - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
      - python-dateutil [required: Any, installed: 2.8.2]
        - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
      - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
      - typing-extensions [required: >=3.7,<5.0, installed: 4.7.1]
    - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
    - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
  - constructs [required: >=10.0.0,<11.0.0, installed: 10.2.68]
    - jsii [required: >=1.84.0,<2.0.0, installed: 1.84.0]
      - attrs [required: >=21.2,<24.0, installed: 23.1.0]
      - cattrs [required: >=1.8,<23.2, installed: 23.1.2]
        - attrs [required: >=20, installed: 23.1.0]
      - importlib-resources [required: >=5.2.0, installed: 5.12.0]
      - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
      - python-dateutil [required: Any, installed: 2.8.2]
        - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
      - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
      - typing-extensions [required: >=3.7,<5.0, installed: 4.7.1]
    - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
    - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
  - jsii [required: >=1.84.0,<2.0.0, installed: 1.84.0]
    - attrs [required: >=21.2,<24.0, installed: 23.1.0]
    - cattrs [required: >=1.8,<23.2, installed: 23.1.2]
      - attrs [required: >=20, installed: 23.1.0]
    - importlib-resources [required: >=5.2.0, installed: 5.12.0]
    - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
    - python-dateutil [required: Any, installed: 2.8.2]
      - six [required: >=1.5, installed: 1.16.0]
    - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
    - typing-extensions [required: >=3.7,<5.0, installed: 4.7.1]
  - publication [required: >=0.0.3, installed: 0.0.3]
  - typeguard [required: ~=2.13.3, installed: 2.13.3]
packaging==23.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity I needed to change how my imports were being called. I was able to manually look through the `imports` dir and [Terraform docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs) to determine the correct imports and methods.

Here is an example of my update imports and code in `main.py`

```py
from constructs import Construct
from cdktf import App, TerraformStack, CloudBackend, NamedCloudWorkspace
from imports.azurerm import (
    provider,
    virtual_desktop_workspace,
    virtual_desktop_host_pool,
    virtual_desktop_application_group,
    virtual_network,
    subnet,
)


class MyStack(TerraformStack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
        super().__init__(scope, id)

        # Initialize the Azure provider
        provider.AzurermProvider(self, "azure", features={})

        # Create a Virtual Network
        virtual_net = virtual_network.VirtualNetwork(
            self,
            "virtual-network",
            name="my-vnet",
            location="westus2",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-resource-group",
            address_space=["10.0.0.0/16"],
        )

        # Create the virtual subnet for the virtual network
        virtual_subnet = subnet.Subnet(
            self,
            name="azure-vd-subnet",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-resource-group",
            virtual_network_name=virtual_net.name,
            address_prefixes=["10.0.1.0/24"],
            id_="azure-vd-subnet-id",
        )

        # Create an Azure Virtual Desktop Workspace
        workspace = virtual_desktop_workspace.VirtualDesktopWorkspace(
            self,
            "workspace",
            name="virtual-desktop-workspace",
            location="westus2",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-resource-group",
        )

        # Create an Azure Virtual Desktop Host Pool
        host_pool = virtual_desktop_host_pool.VirtualDesktopHostPool(
            self,
            "host-pool",
            name="virtual-desktop-host-pool",
            location="westus2",
            resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-resource-group",
            friendly_name="Virtual Desktop Host",
            type="Personal",
            load_balancer_type="Persistent",
        )

        # Create an Azure Virtual Desktop Application Group
        application_group = (
            virtual_desktop_application_group.VirtualDesktopApplicationGroup(
                self,
                "application-group",
                name="virtual-desktop-application-group",
                type="Desktop",
                default_desktop_display_name="azure-vd",
                location="westus2",
                resource_group_name="virtual-desktop-application-group-resource-group",
                host_pool_id=host_pool.id,
                friendly_name="Virtual Desktop Application Group",
            )
        )


app = App()
stack = MyStack(app, "azure_vd")
CloudBackend(
    stack,
    hostname="app.terraform.io",
    organization="redacted",
    workspaces=NamedCloudWorkspace("azure_vd_poc"),
)

app.synth()
```

I am now successfully able to `cdktf synth` which is generating the `cdktf.out` dir, `stacks` dir and `manifest.json` correctly.

EDIT:

My initial answer works, but to my understanding it is not completely correct as it is just a "local"  import.

The correct way is calling the `cdktf_cdktf_provider_azurerm`.

```
from constructs import Construct
from cdktf import TerraformStack, AzurermBackend
from cdktf_cdktf_provider_azurerm import (
    data_azurerm_client_config,
    nat_gateway,
    nat_gateway_public_ip_association,
    network_security_group,
    network_security_rule,
    provider,
    public_ip,
    resource_group,
    subnet,
    subnet_nat_gateway_association,
    subnet_network_security_group_association,
    virtual_network,
    virtual_network_gateway,
)
```

Comment: does cdktf create a virtual environment? why is pipenv required?